# regarding error "Range must be bounded by constant expressions"

Tags: verilog

```
always @(numint or numfrac)
  begin
     begin : BIT_DET
     for (i=22;i>0;i=i-1)
       begin
         if (numint[i]==1'b1)
           begin

           ieeesign <= numsign ;
            ieeeexp [7:0] <=  127+i;
            ieeemant[22:0] <= { numint[i-1:0] , numfrac[22:i] } ;
            ieeeop [31:0] <=  { ieeesign, ieeeexp , ieeemant[22:0] } ;
            disable BIT_DET;
           end
     end
   end
  end
endmodule
```

Please tell me how can i remove the error?

Comment: Is that the full text of the error? What line is it on? Your question could use a little more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is for `[i-1:0]` and `[22:i]`. Part-select cannot have a variable range. Bit-select can use a variable. Each bit of `ieeemant` needs to be assigned individually.

Change:

```
ieeemant[22:0] <= { numint[i-1:0] , numfrac[22:i] } ;
```

to:

```
for(j=0; j<23; j+=1) begin
    ieeemant[j] <= (i+j < 23) ? numfrac[j+i] : numint[j-i];
end
```